# Android app upgrade

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I've an android app on the market, which I've built through the online PhoneGap Build service. Now I want to upgrade it to next version, so I create a new app via PhoneGap Build.

Unfortunately, when i try to put them in the market as the app upgrade, it returns me an error, saying that there is a problem in the versionCode. 
I know that the versionCode in the AndroidManifest must be higher than the previous one, in order to upgrade the app successfully, so I set the version to 1.2.

Which could be the error? Is it possible that the market returns me a false error? I mean, that the error is another one?

Anyone experienced anything like this?
Any advice?
Thanks to all!

Comment: why don't you reuse the origional project and update it's version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you're updating both the `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName` attributes in the manifest.

Also, make sure that the value in `versionCode` is just an integer (which you increase with each new release). The symbolic version, "1.2", should go in the `versionName` field.

Comment: Ok, so the android:versionName must also be different from the first release?

Comment: Are you putting "1.2" in the versionName or versionCode? versionCode is supposed to be an integer. You increment versionCode from 1 to 2, for example, and then put the symbolic "1.2" in the versionName field. If you are trying to put "1.2" in the versionCode field, which is only expecting an integer, then that's what's causing the confusion.

Comment: Thanks Graham!! You save my time and my head ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that you need to check.

1. The package name has to be the same and signed with the same key.
2. Version code problems are usually due to one of two things:

   a. android:versionCode is not an integer.  This has to be a whole number incremented for each new version.  An app can have the same versionName as long as the version Code is higher for the update.  First version android:versionCode="1", upgrade versionCode="2"

   b. android:versionName has been updated but the versionCode is the same. i.e android:versionName was changed from "1.5" to "1.6" but the versionCode is still set to "1".

Comment: Thank you too for your precious advice